# How to mock a service using Jasmine to ignore any calls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit tests for below controller. I have two functions loadCountries and loadTimezones that I want to be called on page load. I want to test that countries are loaded on page load. In that particular test, I don't care whether timezones are loaded or not. So I mocked Timezones services. But looks like I've to return a value for timezones mock. I don't want to handle it explicitly. I was expecting when I do createSpyObj, any function calls that are not explicitly handled on the spy/mock will be dropped or will have no effect. If I don't chain returnValue, mock is calling real function. How do I fix this ?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nileLeApp')
.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope, $translate, $timeout, vcRecaptchaService, Auth, Country, Timezone, RecaptchaService) {
    $scope.success = null;
    $scope.error = null;
    $scope.doNotMatch = null;
    $scope.errorUserExists = null;
    $scope.registerAccount = {};
    $timeout(function () {
        angular.element('[ng-model="registerAccount.email"]').focus();
    });

    $scope.loadCountries = function () {
        Country.getCountries()
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.countries = result.data;
            });
    };

    $scope.loadTimezones = function () {
        Timezone.getTimezones()
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.timezones = result.data;
            });
    };

    $scope.loadCountries();
    $scope.loadTimezones();
});
```

Below is the test I'm trying.

```
'use strict';

describe('Register Controllers Tests', function () {

describe('RegisterController', function () {

    // actual implementations
    var $scope;
    var $q;
    // mocks
    var MockTimeout;
    var MockTranslate;
    var MockAuth;
    var MockCountry;
    var MockTimezone;
    // local utility function
    var createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $q = $injector.get('$q');
        $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        MockTimeout = jasmine.createSpy('MockTimeout');
        MockAuth = jasmine.createSpyObj('MockAuth', ['createAccount']);
        MockCountry = jasmine.createSpyObj('MockCountry', ['getCountries']);
        MockTimezone = jasmine.createSpyObj('MockTimezone', ['getTimezones']);
        MockTranslate = jasmine.createSpyObj('MockTranslate', ['use']);


        var locals = {
            '$scope': $scope,
            '$translate': MockTranslate,
            '$timeout': MockTimeout,
            'Auth': MockAuth,
            'Country': MockCountry,
            'Timezone': MockTimezone
        };
        createController = function () {
            $injector.get('$controller')('RegisterController', locals);
        };
    }));

    it('should load countries on page load', function () {

        var mockCountryResponse = {data: [{
            'countryId': 1,
            'alpha2Code': "AF",
            'countryName': "Afghanistan"
        }]};

        MockCountry.getCountries.and.returnValue($q.resolve(mockCountryResponse.data));
        // Want to avoid explicitly specifying below line            
        MockTimezone.getTimezones.and.returnValue($q.resolve({}));

        // given
        createController();

        $scope.$apply($scope.loadCountries);
        expect($scope.countries).toEqual(mockCountryResponse);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get rid of `and.returnValue` here, because the controller chains a promise and expects the methods on the object that `Timezone.getTimezones` stub would return (and it returns none).

`jasmine.createSpyObj` only handles the calls to `Timezone` methods and not their return values, that's why `and.returnValue` is there.

It is totally fine to do

```
MockTimezone.getTimezones.and.returnValue($q.resolve({}));
```

in promise-based specs.